# Cloth Pinning checkbox missing in Blender 2.8

Tags: cloth-simulation

There is no option to pin a vertex group to hold the cloth at the position!
[image]

---

2.79 had this feature 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh I missed that!
It is under `Shape` Menu.
[image]